# How to create an array of objects in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11

I am new to C++. I am from Java background. I have two classes called `SalesPerson` and `SalesPeople`.

I want to create an array of `SalesPerson` in `SalesPeople` class. Below is my program and I get some compilation errors.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class SalesPerson {

    private:
    string name;
    static const int MONTHS = 12;
    double salesPerMonthArray[MONTHS];

    public:
    SalesPerson(string name, double salesPerMonthArray[]) {

        this->name = name;

        for(int i = 0; i < MONTHS; i++) {
            this->salesPerMonthArray[i] = salesPerMonthArray[i];
        }
    }

    string getName() {
        return name;
    }

    double getSalesForAMonth(int month) {

        if(month < MONTHS) {
            return salesPerMonthArray[month];
        }
        return salesPerMonthArray[0];
    }

    double computeAnnualSales() {

        double annualSales = 0.0;
        for(int i = 0; i < MONTHS; i++) {
            annualSales += salesPerMonthArray[i];
        }

        return annualSales;
    }
};

class SalesPeople {

    private:
        int index = 0;
        SalesPerson salesPersonArray[10];

    public:

        void addSalesPerson(SalesPerson salesPerson) {
            salesPersonArray[index] = salesPerson;
            index++;
        }

        SalesPerson getSalesPerson(int index) {
            return salesPersonArray[index];
        }
};

int main() {

    double salesArray[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12};
    SalesPeople salesPeople;

    SalesPerson salesPerson1("yaswanth", salesArray);

    salesPeople.addSalesPerson(salesPerson1);

    return 0;
}
```

Compilation errors:

```
prog.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
prog.cpp:65:14: error: use of deleted function ‘SalesPeople::SalesPeople()’
  SalesPeople salesPeople;
              ^
prog.cpp:44:7: note: ‘SalesPeople::SalesPeople()’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
 class SalesPeople {
       ^
prog.cpp:44:7: error: no matching function for call to ‘SalesPerson::SalesPerson()’
prog.cpp:44:7: note: candidates are:
prog.cpp:12:2: note: SalesPerson::SalesPerson(std::string, double*)
  SalesPerson(string name, double salesPerMonthArray[]) {
  ^
prog.cpp:12:2: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 0 provided
prog.cpp:4:7: note: SalesPerson::SalesPerson(const SalesPerson&)
 class SalesPerson {
       ^
prog.cpp:4:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
prog.cpp:4:7: note: SalesPerson::SalesPerson(SalesPerson&&)
prog.cpp:4:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
```

Then I tried to create an empty constructor and I got the below error.

```
prog.cpp: In constructor ‘SalesPeople::SalesPeople()’:
prog.cpp:51:17: error: no matching function for call to ‘SalesPerson::SalesPerson()’
   SalesPeople() {
                 ^
prog.cpp:51:17: note: candidates are:
prog.cpp:12:2: note: SalesPerson::SalesPerson(std::string, double*)
  SalesPerson(string name, double salesPerMonthArray[]) {
  ^
prog.cpp:12:2: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 0 provided
prog.cpp:4:7: note: SalesPerson::SalesPerson(const SalesPerson&)
 class SalesPerson {
       ^
prog.cpp:4:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
prog.cpp:4:7: note: SalesPerson::SalesPerson(SalesPerson&&)
prog.cpp:4:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
prog.cpp: In constructor ‘SalesPeople::SalesPeople()’:
prog.cpp:51:17: error: no matching function for call to ‘SalesPerson::SalesPerson()’
   SalesPeople() {
                 ^
prog.cpp:51:17: note: candidates are:
prog.cpp:12:2: note: SalesPerson::SalesPerson(std::string, double*)
  SalesPerson(string name, double salesPerMonthArray[]) {
  ^
prog.cpp:12:2: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 0 provided
prog.cpp:4:7: note: SalesPerson::SalesPerson(const SalesPerson&)
 class SalesPerson {
       ^
prog.cpp:4:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
prog.cpp:4:7: note: SalesPerson::SalesPerson(SalesPerson&&)
prog.cpp:4:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
```

How can I create an array of user defined objects in C++?

Comment: By creating an array of type `MyObject` with `MyObject arr[10]`, you _are_ creating an array of `MyObject`s. C++ uses _values_ extensively. Just like creating an `int arr[10]` in Java would actually create 10 ints.

Comment: Your first error (both cases) relates to the default constructor for `SalesPeople`, there isn't one. Either create one appropriately, or create a default constructor for `SalesPerson` so that the compiler generated one for `SalesPeople` is well defined. Simply adding `SalesPerson() {}` to `SalesPerson` will get it to compile, but it may need more work for what you want.

Comment: Are you required to use arrays? Is this an exercise in learning about arrays? If not, using `std::vector` may be a better idea.

Comment: @Niall This is an exercise to learn arrays and classes. I think I cant user vector

Comment: @KrishnaChaitanya, I see there are some nice answers here then. The error really only looks limited to the default constructor (and then the array of double's initialisation).

Comment: I recommend reading up on "the rule of three" and the follow ups "rule of zero" and "rule of five" to get a better understanding of the special member functions associated with a C++ class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You create arrays exactly as you are trying: `Type varname[size];`. The instances in the array must be initialized though and since you don't provide any parameters, the type must have a default constructor, as the compilation error indicates.

You seem to have interpreted the error correctly, but you've presumably only given default constructor to `SalesPeople`. That class contains an array of `SalesPerson`, so you get the same problem if you don't give `SalesPerson` a default constructor as well.

In Java, non-primitive objects are (whether in an array, or bound to a variable) actually references that point to objects in memory. The actual objects are hidden from the programmer and are only accessible through the references. Java references can be set to `null` which means that it doesn't point to any object. That's what all the references in a newly created array are set to and it's why you don't need a default constructor to define an array of objects in Java.

In c++, no value is a reference or a pointer (unless the type itself is a reference/pointer). Only pointers can have `nullptr` value. Once an array is allocated, all the objects inside are constructed. In c++ An array of pointers behaves much more like an array of objects in Java and doesn't require the pointed type to be default-constructible but I recommend using an array of objects unless you need to have an array of objects of sibling types that inherit a common base.

You might want to consider whether it makes sense to have a bunch of default initialized objects rather than an empty `std::vector` that you fill with objects that are constructed with parameters.

It *is* possible to have an array of non-default-constructible objects as well if you know the parameters at the time when the array is defined: `Type varname[size]{{PARAMS0}, {PARAMS1}, ...};` where `ParamsX` are parameter lists for the newly constructed objects.

Comment: After adding a default constructor in SalesPerson It compiled properly. But why should I give a default constructor in SalesPerson? I have never seen such things in Java. Is there any special reason or this is the right way?

Comment: If I recall correctly, Java has no value semantics for non-primitive types. In that language arrays of objects are actually arrays of references to objects and the references are initialized to `null`. That is why you don't need a default constructor for the type to define an array of objects in Java.